# SQL query to duplicate each row 12 times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has columns site,year and sales . this table is unique on site+year eg

```
site  year   sales
-------------------
a     2012    50
b     2013   100
a     2006    35
```

Now what I want to do is make this table unique on site+year+month. Thus each row gets duplicated 12 times, a month column is added which is labelled from 1-12 and the sales values get divided by 12 thus

```
site   year  month  sales
-------------------------
a      2012  1      50/12
a      2012  2      50/12
...
a      2012  12     50/12
...

b      2013   1     100/12 
...
a      2006   12       35/12
```

I am doing this on python currently and it works like a charm, but I need to do this in SQL (ideally PostgreSQL since I will be using this as a datasource for tableau)

It would be very helpful if someone can provide the explanations with the solution as well, since I am a novice at this

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_series()` for that

```
select t.site, t.year, g.month, t.sales / 12
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(1,12) as g (month)
order by  t.site, t.year, g.month;
```

If the column `sales` is an integer, you should cast that to a `numeric` to avoid the integer division: `t.sales::numeric / 12`

Online example: http://rextester.com/GUWPI39685

Comment: Thanks ! very short and elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach (For T-SQL - MS SQL) :

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    [site] VARCHAR(5),  
    [year] INT,   
    sales INT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('A',2012,50),('B',2013,100),('C',2006,35)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        MonthSeq = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        MonthSeq = MonthSeq+1
        FROM CTE
            WHERE MonthSeq <12  
)
SELECT
    T.[site],
    T.[year],
    [Month] = CTE.MonthSeq,
    sales = T.[sales]/12
    FROM CTE
        CROSS JOIN @T T
            ORDER BY T.[site],CTe.MonthSeq
```